# Separate User Library and System Library in RStudio's Packages pane under Windows 10?

Tags: r, rstudio, package, libraries

I'm setting up R/RStudio on a new Windows 10 machine; first time setting it up in a non-UNIX environment, so bear with me.

From my previous experience with R/RStudio under Linux and macOS, I wanted to setup separate libraries for system and user, i.e., that the Packages pane in RStudio would show both a **User Library** *AND* a **System Library**.

I specified the `R_LIBS_USER` environment variable for my account as `C:\Users\[user name]\Documents\R\win-library\3.5`.

When running R/RStudio, the `.libPaths()` are as follows:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/[user name]/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"    
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.0/library"
```

This is pretty much what I wanted: the first library path being the default **User Library**, and the second path being the **System Library**. I'm able to install packages at will, and they are per default located inside the **User Library**.

*HOWEVER*, the Packages pane in RStudio does *NOT* show two separate libraries for the **User Library** and the **System Library**. Instead, all packages (aside from `base`) are shown under **System Library**; including the packages from my **User Library**. My question now is:

Is there a way to tell R/RStudio that my **User Library** and my **System Library** are two separate entities, which should be visually separated in RStudio's Packages pane?

*Note*: I'm aware this is likely a mere "cosmetic" issue; but it still bothers me! Also, I'm not sure if this is a pure R or an RStudio issue, so I tagged both.

**EDIT**: I also noticed that the System Library (`C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.0/library`) is not available as drop-down option when installing new packages inside the Packages pane.

--

```
> devtools::session_info()
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.453)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Nothing to worry about
 tz       This neither               
 date     2018-06-08                  

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 base      * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 compiler    3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 datasets  * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 devtools    1.13.5  2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 graphics  * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 grDevices * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 memoise     1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 methods   * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 stats     * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 tools       3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 utils     * 3.5.0   2018-04-23 local         
 withr       2.1.2   2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 yaml        2.1.19  2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. In my case the cause was using a substituted drive for the user libraries:

```
> subst
F:\: => C:\data\flash drive
```

Setting `R_LIBS_USER` to `F:/[...]` shows the cosmetic error, using `C:/data/flash drive/[...]` works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")`  is as follow:

```
"C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local/R/win-library/4.2"
```

This path includes two backslashes, so this was causing the environment variable to not be recognized correctly.
Next I searched for a place to put .Renviron as follows

```
R.home(component = "etc")
```

I created .Renviron (or Renviro.site) in that folder and saved it with the following in the contents and it worked.

```
R_LIBS_USER=C:/Users/${USERNAME}/AppData/Local/R/win-library/%v
```